Invalid argument type (Text). Expecting a Record value instead
In my Canvas power app, I am trying to send emails to those who are selected in the combo box. From the onSelect of send mail button, I have written the following code.
Set(schoolMails, Concat(ComboboxCanvas1.SelectedItems,'School email address',";"));
Notify(schoolMails);
If(!IsEmpty(ComboboxCanvas1.SelectedItems), SendMailFromCombobox.Run(schoolMails) ,Notify("Please Select Email addresses to send mails!",NotificationType.Error))

Where my concat function is working well and I can see it from the notify. but somehow I am getting the "Invalid argument type (Text). Expecting a Record value instead." error on flow run SendMailFromCombobox.Run(schoolMails). I don't know what I am doing wrong here?

The clue is in the error message. The Concat() function returns text, but the workflow epects a record. Hard to tell how to fix that without seeing more detail about your actual data and the flow trigger.

Why using a powerautomate flow when you can utilize the outlook connector within Powerapps which allows sending email from sharedmailbox? Try it
